# Name field cannot be grouped in query call

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have query in visualforce javascript function.It is throwing the following error "Name field cannot be grouped in query call".Can someone point me why it is giving that error.I saw this error in browser javascript console

Not: FE_Controller__r.Name field is autonumber field

```
var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT id ID,FE_Controller__r.Name CONTROLLER," + 
        "sum(Budget_Expenses__c) BUDGET, Sum(Amount__c) AMOUNT, "  +
        "RecordType.Name TYPE, Funding_Level__c LEVEL, Fiscal_Year__c FY" +
        "FROM FEvent__c " +
        "where status__c !='Cancelled'" +
        "group by id,RecordType.Name, Funding_Level__c," +
        "Fiscal_Year__c,FE_Controller__r.Name ");
```

Comment: Your query is weird, why do you GROUP BY Id? Do you need all the columns?

Comment: yes I need all columns.when I remove FE_Controller__r.Name from query then it is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id ID, FE_Controller__r.Name CONTROLLER,
sum(Budget_Expenses__c) BUDGET, Sum(Amount__c) AMOUNT,
RecordType.Name TYPE, Funding_Level__c LEVEL, Fiscal_Year__c FY,
FROM FEvent__c
where status__c !='Cancelled'
group by id,RecordType.Name, Funding_Level__c, Fiscal_Year__c,FE_Controller__r.Name
```

This shouldn't even compile because you have comma (,) before `FROM` (not to mention unclosed quote)... Probably you cut out some fields to post here?

I'd say that with `GROUP BY Id` the whole idea if aggregation becomes useless. **Every row will be unique because Id is unique. Same with autonumber fields!**

Try with straightforward query?

```
SELECT id, FE_Controller__r.Name,
Budget_Expenses__c, Amount__c,
RecordType.Name, Funding_Level__c, Fiscal_Year__c
FROM FEvent__c
where status__c !='Cancelled'
```

(you can't use column aliases then but normal `result.records[0].FE_Controller__r.Name` should work)

---

Autonumber and formula fields aren't "groupable":

```
System.debug(Schema.sObjectType.Case.fields.CaseNumber.isGroupable()); // false
```

If you really want aggregation by Controller Name and there's only Name field you could make-do with either workflow that'd be writing the generated Name to helper text field. Or split the query into 2:

```
SELECT FE_Controller__c, SUM(Budget_Expenses__c), SUM(Amount__c)
FROM FEvent__c
GROUP BY FE_Controller__c
```

Comment: For testing purpose I have updated the query with another field (FE_Controller_r.Amount__c) on same object and its giving me similar error."Amount__c cannot be grouped in query call"

Comment: And is it a normal field (Number, Currency) or a formula field? (I've never tried to group by rollup summary field). Maybe try to explain what are you trying to achieve, what kind of table of data you'd like to have as a result... Controllers with info of all Events? Aggregated or detailed?

Comment: It is Number field

Comment: You can't group on `__r` fields; see my comment on @JimRae's answer.

Comment: @MikeChale , I swear this works in my org: `SELECT SUM(Value__c), Order__c, MAX(Order__r.Name)
FROM Order_Line_Item__c
GROUP BY Order__c
LIMIT 5`. Call it dirty hack if you wish. Technically the docs are correct ;)

Comment: But in that example you aren't trying to group by `Order__r.foo`, you're grouping by `Order__c`; you aren't traversing the relationship in the GROUP BY.

Comment: As I say - technically correct. But I will get the results I want because even though the MAX(Name) is suspicious it'll be also grouped by Id of the parent record so that in that row Name (and any other field I'll specify) will be effectively tied to only that one parent with that Id :) And my Order__c.Name is an autonumber.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation, you can't use child relationship expressions that use the __r syntax in a query that uses a GROUP BY clause.

If you really need to group this way, you are going to need to refactor your code. I would suggest that you consider using Javascript Remoting, and leveraging a "Wrapper Class" with a map to group the data the way you need.

Comment: He's going "up" not "down" (parent relationship). And I'd swear stuff like that worked for me in the past.

Comment: He said he removed FE_Controller__r.Name and it worked.  Isn't that "down"

Comment: Can you provide a link to that documentation and quote the relevant excerpt?

Comment: "Down" would be a subquery, something that looks like a related list. `SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Email FROM Contacts) FROM Account` is "down". "Up" is via lookup, `SELECT COUNT(Id), Account.Name FROM Contact GROUP BY Account.Name` works fine

Comment: I am going UP ..there is lookup relationship

Comment: "You can't use child relationship expressions that use the __r syntax in a query that uses a GROUP BY clause." http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_group_by_considerations.htm#kanchor54